# where is training data, computed activation's and model parameter stored while training a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I searched a lot but could not find any accurate answer. Some website says that the model parameters and training data are stored on ram and are fetched when are needed, but wouldn't it make the training process slower. Also if the parameters were to be stored on the GPU, why is training a model consuming all my gpu memory? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are stored in system or GPU RAM (where else would they be stored?).

The exception might be training data, if it does not fit into RAM then batch training is used, and only part of the training data (one or several batches) are stored into RAM at a time.